# Warn user that Flash is required

Tags: flash

I have a Flash video embedded into my website. I want to warn any user who doesn't have Flash, or who is using a device that doesn't support Flash, about this. How can can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Put the warning inside the Flash video `<object>` tag, for example:

```
<object> <p> This is a warning </p> </object>
```

or

```
<object> <image src = "warning.jpg" /> </object>
```

Keep in mind that in most cases when a user doesn't have Flash installed on his device, he is notified that he must install Flash in order to view the video, automatically:

[image]
[image]